# I have a lambda mapped to kinesis events. How can I determine the final kinesis event invocation?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-kinesis

I have a producing lambda creating a list of documents and sends them to kinesis in batches 50 at a time. My consuming lambda is invoked on the kinesis event and is processing the documents as intended. My question is how do I determine that the final lambda to process the kinesis events?

My intention is to have a third lambda be invoked on the condition that its the final lambda

Comment: What do you mean by "final kinesis event invocation"?

Comment: I have a producer lambda inputing anywhere from 50-1000 items to kinesis. I have the consumer lambda mapped to the kinesis event, and takes in a batch of 30 at a time. I want to determine if the final batch is being processed so I can invoke the third lambda. So that the third lambda runs once the kinesis stream is emptied again

Comment: You need a fully custom solution for that. For example, you have to keep track of your messages using DynamoDB.